# Why is -ing added to the second verb in this sentence?

Tags: tense, sequence-of-tenses

So I am playing the English version of a game called Baldur's Gate 3. The description of a spell is this:

> This spell allows spellcasters to fire an arrow of electricity that **bursts** on impact, **dealing** additional Lightning damage to creatures in the vicinity

Why are "burst" and "deal" not using the same tense? Or why is "-ing" added to "deal"?

Comment: Because 'dealing additional damage' is the effect of the 'burst'. Compare "I fell on the ice, breaking my wrist." "He stretched out his arm, knocking over a vase."

Comment: Please note: the verb deal is used incorrectly there I just noticed. To mete out or deal out.

Comment: It's an efficient way of conveying the information without resorting to a separate, (and lengthier) finite clause. The clause "dealing additional lightning damage to creatures in the vicinity" has a resultative interpretation. Think of it as "... thus/so dealing additional Lightning damage to creatures in the vicinity". Note that "dealing" is a non-finite verb, so it is untensed.

Comment: @Lambie - 'dealing damage' is a very well established idiom among computer gaming people. When wizards shoot magic lightning bolts, deadly sparkly spells, etc. Much as I sympathise (I detest those games) I fear that you are on a sticky wicket.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yeah, I don't know much about computer games.

Comment: @Lambie - I've been interested in computers since 1965, and owned at least one since 1980, and I have lost count of the number of people who assume that I like games. I hate them.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey My first computer was an Amstrad in 1984 but I worked on a Digital Vax mini-computer before that....so...

Comment: @Lambie - On a school visit aged 13 I was taken to see the LEO 3 shared by 3 London boroughs for rates (tax) and payroll purposes, and in the late 1970s my employers got a Commodore PET which I was allowed to play with (write BASIC programs). In 1981 I inherited a friend's Acorn Atom, got a Sinclair ZX-81 in 1983, and in 1985 a Sinclair QL (of blessed memory!). The rest is history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

> The large man sat on the flimsy chair, **breaking two of its legs**.

The highlighted clause refers to the action, the chair's legs breaking, not as an action that *ensued* in the wake of the first action, but as a direct and *instantaneous* consequence of the first action.

> As he walked across the room he tripped on the carpet, **spilling the glass of tea he held in his hand**.

Semantically, you can imagine the word "thereby" placed between the two clauses:

> The large man sat on the flimsy chair, <sup>thereby</sup> breaking two of its legs.

The actions are synchronous, not asynchronous.

Comment: The large man sat on the flimsy chair, breaking two of its legs. = The large man sat on the flimsy chair and broke two of its legs. As he walked across the room he tripped on the carpet **and spilled** the glass of tea he held in his hand.

Answer (score 1):

In English, we often use **participle phrases** like that instead of repeating the verb from from the main clause.

- He ran out of the room, **screaming** down the hall.
  OR
- He ran out of the room **and screamed** down the hall.

Likewise:
This spell allows spellcasters to fire an arrow of electricity that bursts on impact, **dealing** additional lightning damage to creatures in the vicinity.

This spell allows spellcasters to fire an arrow of electricity that bursts on impact **and deal out additional lightning** damage to creatures in the vicinity.

This structure *usually* applies to active verbs.

deal on its own is not correct.

Comment: Surely it's the 'arrow of electricity' that is the subject of the clause _dealing additional damage_?

Comment: I don't understand that at all. As long as there is the comma, the ing can be made to be "and verb". I fell on the ice **and broke** my wrist. He stretched out his arm and knocked over the vase. I realize that bursts on impact just lengthens the entire thing but it doesn't change my reading as a compound verb VERSUS a participle phrase.

Comment: In those examples there is only one subject.  In the OP's example, the spellcasters fire an arrow that bursts on impact. By doing that, **it** deals additional damage.

Comment: @KateBunting Right, so:  x allows spellcasters **to fire an arrow of electricity** that bursts on impact and to deal additional damage. There is only one subject sure, but there are two verbs. And these sentences, **like the ones you gave** can be rewritten with: and + the active verb. They retain their meaning. They allow children to play in the yard that is so dirty, making them do so every day. They allow children to play in the yard that is so dirty and make them do so every day. Two verbs, one subject.